# I'm using a standard Django login but I'm getting this error: Error exiting in Django 4.2.1

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRu1G.png)message error when clicking link to logout [message error when clicking link to logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9pjq.png)

urlpatterns content django.contrib.auth.urls in urls.py [urlpatterns content django.contrib.auth.urls in urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SrU6.png)

Variable LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in settins.py [Variable LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in settins.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEEHT.png)

file html index content button html logout[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjGQM.png)

I am creating logout, login works less logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the login URL in your app.
In `app.core.urls` add `login` URL.